# Modifying CV generated by vitae package R

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

I've generated a CV using R [vitae](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vitae/readme/README.html) package and `awesomecv` template.

The utilised packages:

```
packageVersion("vitae");
#> [1] '0.2.2.9000'
packageVersion("tibble");
#> [1] '3.0.1'
packageVersion("dplyr");
#> [1] '1.0.0'
packageVersion("tinytex")
#> [1] '0.24'
```

Running:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
```

The simple reproducible example below shows what I am trying to modify - a section of Education with list (bullet-points) to show items in the PhD degree section.

My aim is to modify the indentation of items *_a*, and *_b* and create an appearance that they are subitems of the item *_A*. I would either wish it to be a tab based indentation of five spaces, or anything similar that creates the desired appearance (i.e., that they are a level below item *_A*).
To visualise the desired output (anything similar to this is fine, as long as it doesn't require extensive code / manipulating the latex template itself):

- Item_A

  - Item_a
  - Item_b

**The reproducible example:**

````
---
name: John
surname: Doe
position: ""
address: ""
phone: +44 1234 45687
www: stackoverlow.com
email: "email@gmail.com"
twitter: ""
github: ""
linkedin: ""
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
aboutme: "Hello world"
output: vitae::awesomecv
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tinytex)
```

# Education
```{r education}
tribble(
     ~ degree, ~ uni, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ this_is_the_list,
     "PhD degree", "My Uni",  "Uni Place", "2010 - 2020", "item_A",
     "PhD degree", "My Uni",  "Uni Place", "2010 - 2020", "item_a",
     "PhD degree", "My Uni",  "Uni Place", "2010 - 2020", "item_b") %>% 
  detailed_entries(degree, dates, uni, loc, this_is_the_list)
```
````

**The example output:**

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `.protect = FALSE` in the `detailed_entries()` function, you are able to provide latex inputs directly. Using this, you can create an itemize list within the existing item to get the desired result.

This is admittedly a complex solution to the problem, so I've opened an issue to hopefully improve this in the future: https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/126

````
# Education
```{r education}
tribble(
  ~ degree, ~ uni, ~ loc, ~ dates, ~ this_is_the_list,
  "PhD degree", "My Uni",  "Uni Place", "2010 - 2020", "
   item\\_A
   \\begin{itemize}
     \\item item\\_a
     \\item item\\_b
   \\end{itemize}") %>%
  detailed_entries(degree, dates, uni, loc, this_is_the_list, .protect = FALSE)
```
````

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The solution provided led to what I want to achieve - with a few modifications when used on my real CV:

`"First item,
     \\begin{itemize}
     \\item created a proof-of-concept ...
     \\item wrote the client-side ...
     \\item designed and implemented ...
     \\item coordinated ...
     \\end{itemize}
     \\item The application ...
     \\item The application ...",`

I omitted the first `\\item`, then I removed the escape characters. To continue the list, I needed to re-introduce `\\item` after the `\\end{itemize}`. It also seems `item` is assumed internally?

Comment: Yes, the element is prefixed by item within an itemize environment. This is a big part of why I think the interface needs rethinking - the itemized layout shouldn't be forced upon the user.